# Hoe to clear error style of the TextFormField when I disable it?

Tags: flutter

I know how to validate the text form fields. Therefore, I display an error message when the content of the field is invalid. However, in my case, I have another field that will be enabled when the user checks a CheckBox. In this case, the first field will be disabled.

Now the problem is if I disable the first field when it is showing an error message then this style is still visible when I disable it.

So, my question is, how to clear the error style when I disable the field?

[image]

Comment: You can add a test for the validator ? ```validator: isDisabled?null:Validators.validateEmail()```

Comment: @ikerfah, Thanks for your comment. I already tried that and doesn't work, unfortunately :(

Comment: Could you please post the code ?